# how do i fix unwated semicolon after call function?

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I tried to remove semicolon after function in language angular and editor visual studio . but when i tried to save my code .. It doesn't remove and came back  ..
check semicolon after `ngoninit();`
[image: 1]

Comment: turn off the extension that's addings semi colons

Comment: it worked thanks @poul krujit